# Cycling between view states in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

I've currently got code that displays a string showing that another view state is being activated. How would I go about adding another button that will cycle back through to the previous state, NOT just hiding the string (though effectively that's what it is). Eventually I want to be able to run through multiple methods using view state (including a fileupload and displaying data from a database / data from the document)

My code is as such;

```
<script runat="server"> 
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            string viewStateDisplay = "ViewState 2 is now being displayed";
            if(ViewState["PageState"]==null)
            {
                ViewState["PageState"] = viewStateDisplay;
            }    
         }
   }    
   protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         lblString.Text = ViewState["PageState"].ToString();
   }    
</script>

<div>
    ViewState Data: <b><asp:Label ID="lblString" runat="server"/></b>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Get ViewState Data"
         onclick="btnClick_Click"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "viewstate", you are not talking about the ASP.NET viewstate itself.  It sounds like you are talking about screen flips or changing visible divs or something that makes the screen look different (like a wizard screen) but has nothing to do with the ASP.NET viewstate itself.  Is that correct?

Comment: I think so, I was told to use viewstates and was given an example of what it looks like. Are ASP.NET viewstates a different thing? All I want to do is replace one section of a page with another while hiding other sections.

Answer (score 0):

Added another button and edited the other one so it looks like this. This can be used to test my methods that I will place inside and give viewstate numbers and close them according to their number, the button now gives me a way to test this is working.

```
 protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    lblString.Text = ViewState["PageState"].ToString();
    lblString.Visible = true;

   }

   private void Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       lblString.Visible = !lblString.Visible;
       lblString.Visible = false;
   }

ViewState Data: <b><asp:Label ID="lblString" runat="server"/></b>
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Get ViewState Data" OnClick="btnClick_Click"/>
<asp:Button ID="Closeform" runat="server" Text ="Hide PageState" OnClick="Close" />
```